# plt.show() not showing data instead holding it for next plot (spyder)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I have been using the same setup for quite some time now but suddenly I am no longer allowed to plot more than one graph in a program.
Usually I can plot multiple plots after each other and let the program run through it. It executes the next lines of code after closing the first window. However, recently the first plot is not shown but instead the data is added to the last plot.

I have included a sample code which used to give me two plots but now only one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

random_num = np.random.randint(0,5,10)
random_num_2 = np.random.randint(0,100,10)

plt.plot(random_num, 'ko')
plt.show()

plt.plot(random_num_2, 'g*')
plt.show()
```

The first image shows the output from my program. But I would like to have them separated into two plots like Figure 2 and 3 show.

[image: What my program is giving me]
[image: First graph I would like to see]
[image: Second graph I would like to see]

Maybe I should add that I am using Python 3.6 with Spyder 3.2.4. The graphics option is set to display it in Qt5 even though I tried all settings and only 'Inline' shows me the results the way I want it.

Sorry if this is a very simple question. I have tried googling but I only come up with questions about my topic where the way mine works would be the solution not the problem.

Comment: Simply open a new figure with plt.figure() for each new plot (after plt.show())

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working.

Comment: or try `plt.draw()` instead of `plt.show()`

Comment: It's as far as I know due to the switch in Spyder 3 to use QT5 by default.

Comment: Does it not work when **un**ticking "Activate Support" in Spyder Preferences / IPython Console / Graphics / Support for Graphics ?

Answer (score 2):

@TheresaOtt. I would suggest you create a new figure instance (`plt.figure()`) for each plot and use only once at the end the `plt.show()` command.

Comment: Would I put the plt.figure() command in front of each plot or after?

Comment: @TheresaOtt Before each plot. sandwich your picture content by plt.figure() and plt.show()